# Getting the "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'err' referenced before assignment"

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

So, I've been trying to do this code in which I just need it to print through the sys library a variable I made, but it will always give me the "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'err' referenced before assignment", No matter what  did.

I have already tried making the variable a global one, but it will give me "SyntaxError: annotated name 'err' can't be global" problem.

```
import sys

RED   = "\033[1;31m" 
RESET = "\033[0;0m"

red = sys.stdout.write(RED)
reset = sys.stdout.write(RESET)

def error():

  err:"""
    File "main.py", line 614
      route()
                  ^
  Error: expected an story progression
  """
  red()

  for char in erri:
    sys.stdout.write(char)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    sleep(0.05)

  reset()
```

It would be really nice if I could just print the 'err' variable. It's weird that all those problems showed up, because I've done that with other variables and definitions and everything went by smoothly.

Comment: You have `err:"""` instead of `err="""`

Comment: You also have an undefined variable `erri`.